# Quick Admin Panel | Unable to locate a class or view for component (only when live)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to get a Laravel 8 project up and running on Hostinger's shared hosting. I realize I'm already complicating things but have successfully set things up besides the components. I am using Povilas' Quick Admin Panel (Livewire ver), and it's this that requires components that are only 'missing' when on production server. Everything runs smoothly on localhost.

I've read that this may be caused by namespace issues - the environment may have case sensitivity (if so, how can I work around?). Other posts explained how each component should be visible in Http\View\Components as well as in resources\views\components. I've also read something on the existence of default/packaged components but can not find documentation on these individual ones.

I am looking for components 'x-application-logo', 'x-dropdown', 'x-dropdown-link', 'x-responsive-nav-link', and more. I do not see ANY of these in my local files, yet it all works fine in a local environment.

Yes, I've seen very many similar questions asked. However, in all of those cases, the askers were able to visually locate their component files, or were using self-declared components...

Has anyone working with Quick Admin Panel had similar issues?

I've attempted:
php artisan cache:clear, config:clear, view:clear,
php artisan optimize,
composer dump-autoload,
recompiling with npm then reuploading files,
composer install (and composer2 install)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing a fresh instance of Jetstream to copy over its source files. After a few tweaks I got *something* to work without errors... As I've come to find out, the entire admin panel that I was working with had wiped itself, and for some reason started requiring an instance of Jetstream?? I have no recollection of touching any sort of configuration regarding this, so either there's a carbon monoxide leak in my home, or Hostinger is deciding to automatically mess with my Laravel files for one reason or another. Thankfully I have a proper local version of my project, which I will use to reattempt.